# SessionFactory can't be got after compiling to jar by maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, sessionfactory

I'm using Hibernate integrated with Spring, please find bean for `SessionFactory` as below, all works well in Eclipse, however, sessionFactory can't be got after compiling to jar (`mvn install`), I mean the session got from the sessionFactory would be null.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceOri" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EHCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">1024</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>ClassA.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>ClassB.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>ClassC.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The `*.hbm.xml` files are in `src/main/resources`, and I checked the classpath after the compiling and found nothing.

Could anyone help to give any advice about it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach the error logs.

Comment: Classes and additional configuration. What is null? Also you don't have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `hibernate.properties` somewhere/

Comment: @HarbeerKadian The error is NullPointerException caused by null session got from session factory, actually the root cause is sessionFactory bean initialized failed.

Comment: @M.Deinum Hibernate I used is integrated in spring, so there is no hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate.properties.

Comment: Thanks you all man, I resolve this question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found there are two hibernate-commons-annotations jars with different version in my classpath.

```
/Users/name/aa-o/target/aa-o-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/doctor-o-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/name/aa-o/target/aa-o-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.5.6.Final.jar
```

In the running triggered in Eclipse, hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.0.Final.jar works and all's well, I get the log

```
INFO [qtp1412752396-16] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.0.Final}
```

However, in the running triggered by shell script, hibernate-commons-annotations-3.5.6.Final.jar is chosen and system failed. And log is like

```
INFO [qtp1412752396-16] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {3.5.6.Final}
```